# .email gTLD not working for Nginx

Tags: nginx

Is it something special that is needed to get a *.email-domain to work on Nginx?

Same config is used for all domains:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .domain.email .myotherdomain.com;
    root /home/foobar/domain.email/public;
```

It does work when I go to myotherdomain.com, and cartero.email goes to the default 404 of Nginx.

Comment: Have you reloaded your config?

Comment: yes, that's not the problem. it's *.email specific.